# How to silence Nim compile and run output?

Tags: nim-lang

If I run `nim c -r test.nim` the following code in Nim

```
echo "Hi"
```

It would print the result with additional information

```
$ nim c -r test.nim 
Hint: used config file '/usr/local/Cellar/nim/1.2.6/nim/config/nim.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: widestrs [Processing]
Hint: io [Processing]
Hint: test [Processing]
CC: stdlib_system.nim
CC: test.nim
Hint:  [Link]
Hint: 14204 LOC; 0.898 sec; 18.598MiB peakmem; Debug build; proj: /Users/alex/tmp/nim/test.nim; out: /Users/alex/tmp/nim/test [SuccessX]
Hint: /Users/alex/tmp/nim/test
Hi
```

Is there a way to tell it to print only the result, the

```
Hi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--hints:on|off|list` option:

```
nim c -r --hints:off test.nim
```

Note that warnings and errors will still be reported when hints are turned off. You can turn off warnings too with `--warnings:on|off|list`. These and other compiler switches [are described here](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html).

Comment: Thanks, do you know a similar option for `nimble run`?

Comment: @AlexCraft -- You can pass compiler flags to `nimble run`, but I don't know how you could silence `nimble` itself.